# Infinitely many prime factors in a sequence

Tags: number-theory

Given a rational number $q>1$, does there exist infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $p\mid \lfloor q^n\rfloor$ for some $n$?

Even if the weakened question that whether there exists a $q$ satisfying the requirement above seems difficult to solve by elementary methods.

Any comments and hints are welcome.

Comment: If $q$ is an integer, then the set of primes dividing some $\lfloor q^n\rfloor$ is finite.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks a lot! Are there any consequence for a given $q$, e.g. $q=3/2$?